# How to manage changes of the app with different env with git branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bitbucket, git-branch

I have a Rails app with two environments `(staging and production)`. I have my project in Bitbucket. I have created a `branch (staging-branch)` from `master` which I use for `deploying` in staging environment.

Once my staging works I would need to deploy the few of the changes from staging to production and not the whole changes that I made for the staging. In this case, if I create a `pull request` in bitbucket it takes all the files that were changed and adds it to be pulled from master.

However, I want to move only certain files to the production. How can I do this? What approach should I follow for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I would take to this.

The first, and preferable, one is to use proper, atomic feature- and hotfix branches. These would contain any and all changes required to implement a certain feature, or fix a certain issue. Once you have merged this branch into `staging` and verified it works the way you want, you can simply merge the same branch into `production`.

This requires a certain amount of diligence about keeping your commit history clean, and not mixing up different features or fixes in the same branch.

At work, we use GitHub Flow with great results: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

The second one, if you are developing directly on the `staging` branch, is to create a new branch and use `git cherry-pick` to select only the changes that you want to go into `production`, and then merge this new branch in.

Here is the manual for `git cherry-pick`: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

The latter one certainly feels like a hack, and might give you problems with keeping track of how `staging` and `production` have diverged--and although I would not suggest it as a permanent solution, I included it as an option that can be used to solve your immediate problem.